# socket.io in node.js: socket.emit doesn't complete before socket.disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use node.js as a server with socket.io (over a `https` connection server object, client connecting with option `secure: true`) with a JavaScript front end.

On the server if a login attempt fails I am calling:

```
socket.emit('unauthorized');
socket.disconnect();
```

On the client side I have:

```
this.Socket = io.connect(server, { secure: true });
this.Socket.on('disconnect', this.Socket_Disconnect);
this.Socket.on('unauthorized', this.Socket_Unauthorized);
```

I am able to see the disconnect event firing (with arguments set as `['booted']` regardless of whether i pass any arguments to `socket.disconnect()`, but the unauthorized event never makes it.  Am I attempting to pass this message the wrong way?

The rationale I have here is that I want to be able to send different types of `disconnect` events like:

`logout` - clients should stop trying to connect until a user logs in

`server reboot` - clients should reattempt connection until they get through

I need to be able to tell on the client side *why* a client was disconnected by the server, is there at least some way to make sure a message has sent before calling `socket.disconnect()`?

Edit: this appears specific to the node.js `cluster` code - when the application is run on a single thread it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by setting up a Redis server and configuring socket.io to use it within node.js if anyone finds this looking for a solution to the issue.